# Swift View Controller blank when attempting to load image from tableView

Tags: ios, swift

Bear with me as I’m a novice programmer. I'm building out a project where a user goes into their photo library, selects a photo and displays the image's name in a tableView. They can select that image in the tableView and it will then load a full size of that image.

Problem: When I click the row item in the tableView to load the image, the new view controller is just a white screen and not the image previously selected.

Here is the view controller that displays the image:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var selectedImage: String?
    @IBOutlet var image: UIImageView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let imageToLoad = selectedImage {
            image.image = UIImage(named: imageToLoad)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }
    
}
```

Here is where the new view is loaded:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if let dvc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController {
        
        dvc.selectedImage = imageArray[indexPath.row].image
        
        navigationController?.pushViewController(dvc, animated: true)
        
    }
    
}
```

The photos are picked using a navBar button item and loaded into the imageArray of type Photo here:

```
    @objc func loadImage() {
        
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.delegate = self
        present(picker, animated: true)
        
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else { return }
        let imageName = UUID().uuidString
        let imagePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(imageName)
        
        // Convert to JPEG data
        
        if let jpegData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) {
            // We have a valid photo
            try? jpegData.write(to: imagePath)
        }
        
        let photo = Photo(name: "Unkown", image: imageName)
        imageArray.append(photo)
        tableView.reloadData()
        
        dismiss(animated: true)
       
    }
    
    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
  
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return paths[0]
    }
```

And finally here is the Photo class that holds the photo data

```
import UIKit

class Photo: NSObject {
    
    var name: String
    var image: String
    
    init(name: String, image: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
    }
    
}
```

I can see the image name string populated in the debugger when the new view controller is loading, but for some reason it’s just a white screen displayed.

> New Detail View Controller

```
@IBOutlet var image: UIImageView!
var url = URL(string: "")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) {
        image.image = UIImage(data: data)            
    }
}
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

> New didSelectRowAt method

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if let dvc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController {
        

        let imageName = UUID().uuidString
        let urlString = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(imageName)
        dvc.url = urlString
        
        navigationController?.pushViewController(dvc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not call `super.viewWillAppear` in `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Still getting a blank screen when selecting the item from the tableView though. I'm wondering if the imageName isn't getting set correctly and thus doesn't exist when it attempts to assign it to the image view on my other view controller. I do see an image name in my imageArray though. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, I see the problem. I’ll write up an answer. Nicely asked by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
image.image = UIImage(named: imageToLoad)
```

You won’t find the image that way. That method looks in the app bundle. That’s not where the image is.

You need to fetch the image from where you put it, in the Documents directory, using essentially the reverse of the way you saved it. Get the Documents directory url, form the image file url, and load the image data from that url using the Data struct and then create the UIImage from the data.

So once you have calculated the url for this image, exactly the way you calculated it to save it in the first place, you will say

```
if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
     image.image = UIImage(data: data)
}
```

Comment: So that is what I'm doing in the getDocumentsDirectory() method in the second to last block of code I believe. Do I need to somehow use that return value in my other view controller to load the image?

Comment: That’s just a utility but you certainly need to promote its scope because you need it in multiple classes.

Comment: I appreciate the help. After toying around for awhile I appear to still not be getting it. What I did was I created a URL variable in my DetailViewController (where the image is displayed). In the didSelectRowAt method, I passed in the return value of getDocumentsDirectory() to that url variable. I then used that url variable in the if let block you provided above. Still a white screen. Does that sound like the correct implementation?

Comment: Well, I can't see your code _now_. Your question was what was wrong with your code _then_. And I told you the answer to that. You are saving your image by calculating a file URL as `let imagePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(imageName)`. You need to make _exactly_ that same calculation in order to read that image from where you saved it. You can't put your car keys in your top drawer and then expect to find them in your pants pocket.

Comment: Could you take a look at the new code I added in the bottom of my original post? I've calculated the file URL (it looks like a file path - (file:///Users/cookiecutter/Library/Developer/etc). The try block does not appear to be going through though. I believe that means that it's not finding any data when attempting to set the data variable to the url as a Data type. Is that correct? Why could that be?

Comment: Ok but look at your `didSelect`. You are calling `let imageName = UUID().uuidString` _again_, which makes up a _different name_ for this image. The question is what the image name _really is_. You need the name that you gave it when you originally saved it. You were fetching that correctly before with `imageArray[indexPath.row].image` and now you're throwing that away? This is rapidly becoming just silly. Also, no, a string is not a URL. Just do what you were doing before; fetch the real name string and pass it, and let the detail controller work out the URL and open the image.

Comment: Wow I finally got it thanks to you. Appreciate you hanging with me through that...lots to learn. Thanks again.